# Troubleshooting Custom UITableView Cell [Swift]

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I have created a custom UITableView cell in my Storyboard that looks like this:

[image]

I hooked it up to my UITableViewCell class like this:

import UIKit

```
class StatusCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var InstrumentImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var InstrumentType: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var InstrumentValue: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
}
```

Finally I attempted to initialize the UITableView from my UIViewController as such:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!

let Items = ["Altitude","Distance","Groundspeed"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.Items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: StatusCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as StatusCell!

    cell.InstrumentType?.text = Items[indexPath.row]
    cell.InstrumentValue?.text = "150 Km"
    cell.InstrumentImage?.image = UIImage(named: Items[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

However, when I attempt to run the program I get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error:

[image]

What could I have done wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you add 'cellIdentifier' in Interface builder for your cell?

Comment: The "Restoration ID" is set to 'Cell' for my custom cell in the Identity Inspector.

Comment: You need to set 'Reuse Identifier', not the 'Restoration ID'.

Comment: In the Attributes Inspector for my custom cell, there is a field called 'Identifier' where the default value is 'Reuse Identifier' and I've left that field alone.

Comment: There should be 'Cell' for your case

Comment: I have changed that as per this screenshot: https://imgur.com/hrqDZwc but I get the same error at runtime

Comment: Upon re-reading your earlier comment I went back and deleted 'Cell' from Restoration ID. Now I get this error: https://imgur.com/iO5Pg4R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debugger output shows that `cell` is `nil`, meaning it could not be instantiated. Furthermore, you are forcing an unwrapping of the optional (using the `!`) which causes the app to crash on the `nil` value.

Try to change your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like so (notice the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as StatusCell

    cell.InstrumentType.text = Items[indexPath.row]
    cell.InstrumentValue.text = "150 Km"
    cell.InstrumentImage.image = UIImage(named: Items[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

Assuming that your custom tableViewCell class is correctly set up and the outlets are bound, there is no need to check for optionals.

Place a breakpoint on the `let cell = ...` line and step through the code. Check if `cell` gets initialized and is not `nil`.

***And please:*** Do not use upper case names for properties and variables (your outlets, `Items` array...) as upper case names are for classes, structs, ...

Comment: Thank you for the input, I have just fixed the upper-case variables. As for the code, I inserted a number of breakpoints a found that the `let cell` line executed as well as the next two. When I pressed continue after a breakpoint on `cell.InstrumentValue.text` I got this error and get confused: https://imgur.com/RUIqkay

Comment: Double check if your outlets are correctly bound in InterfaceBuilder. To be sure, delete and recreate them.

Comment: Thank you so much! It turns out I had incorrectly bounded my outlets originally. Have a great day!